# I am unable to make a commit inside my organization

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Sorry if someone already asked this but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I have an issue with commiting my changes to already existing branch inside my organization.
We are building a simple movie app with React.js for couple months already, I did a few commits before and created couple branches without any problems, but after reinstalling my Windows 10 month ago, I have run into  problems like this in the picture below:

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGBUm.png)   [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fieE7.png)

The second image has few thousands lines of error code for some kind of reason.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you didn't use to have any problems, it looks like either you weren't linting on commit before, or the linter configuration was not restored correctly.

Comment: This isn't a Git problem, it's a code problem. Your code is failing linting.

Comment: More specifically, it's trying to lint your build files. Make sure you add an ignore for the build directory because you won't want to lint that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I managed to create a eslintignore file in root directory and added this to it:                                                                             build/**
**/*.js
**/*.css                                                                                                                                             ,thousands of error code lines dissapeared and now I am up to like 700-800 but am still unable to commit, did I put something wrong in eslintignore or ?

Comment: Thanks everyone once again, it was a problem with .lintignore, because for some reason, it didn't ignore the rules set inside, it didn't ignore build folder and that's why I had so much errors on this. I had to create another separate branch and push my new app code to it, and it got resolved.